# Calculating the fill area of QPainterPath

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

In a qgraphicsItem  using QPainterPath in paint() function i have drawn a free form drawing over the scene.I'd like to ask if there's a way to calculate the area of a closed painter path. I'd like to display the area the painterpath covered in the scene not as the boundingRect.

Comment: define "calculate the area". For me it is mathematical term and result should be a single number, but you have wrote something about "display the area" so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: thx for reply first. the mathematical term only. i can able to calculate the rect it covers using the path::boundingRect() but how i can display the exact pixels it covers in the region we draw the painterpath.

Comment: Here is the first hint in my search: http://www.wikihow.com/Sample/Area-of-an-Irregular-Polygon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To calculate area of polygon you can do in two ways:

slow but universal (there might be problem with precision): get point from [pointAtPercent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qpainterpath.html#pointAtPercent) with some step and perform [standard calculation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonArea.html) for such polygon

fast but will work only for QPainterPath which segments are [LineToElement](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qpainterpath.html#ElementType-enum). Just iterate through all polygon corners using [elementAt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qpainterpath.html#elementAt) and elementCount and again perform [standard calculation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonArea.html) to calculate area of polygon.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not totally sure if this is what you are looking for, but if you simply want to fill the area of a closed painter path, there is a [QPainter::fillPath](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#fillPath) function:

```
void QPainter::fillPath ( const QPainterPath & path, const QBrush & brush )
```

Answer (score 2):

PyQt/PySide method for non-self-intersecting polygons:

```
def frange(start, stop, step):
    '''Helper float generator'''
    while start < stop:
        yield start
        start += step

def painterPathArea(path, precision = 10000):
    '''QPainterPath area calculation'''
    points = [(point.x(), point.y()) for point in (path.pointAtPercent(perc) for perc in frange (0, 1, 1.0 / precision))]
    points.append(points[0])

    return 0.5 * abs(reduce(
        lambda sum, i: sum + (points[i][0] * points[i + 1][1] - points[i + 1][0] * points[i][1]),
        xrange (len (points) - 1),
        0
    ))
```

Same without reduce:

```
def painterPathArea(path, precision = 10000):
    '''QPainterPath area calculation'''
    points = [(point.x(), point.y()) for point in (path.pointAtPercent(perc) for perc in frange (0, 1, 1.0 / precision))]
    points.append(points[0])

    sum = 0
    for i in xrange (len (points) - 1):
        sum += points[i][0] * points[i + 1][1] - points[i + 1][0] * points[i][1]

    return abs(sum) / 2
```

In fact precision is just the number of vertices of the approximating polygon. The more, the better and slower.

Answer (score 1):

```
qreal getPathArea(QPainterPath *p, qreal step)
{
    QPointF a,b;
    qreal len;
    qreal area=0;
    for(len=0; len<p->length(); len+=step)
    {
        a=p->pointAtPercent(p->percentAtLength(len));
        b=p->pointAtPercent(p->percentAtLength(len+step>p->length()?p->length():len+step));
        area+=(b.x()-a.x())*(a.y+b.y);
    }
    return area/qreal(2);
}
```

Comment: I assume this is taken from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/area-of-a-polygon-with-given-n-ordered-vertices/   However this his does not compile.. IMHO if you replace "area+=(b.x()-a.x())*(a.y+b.y)" with "area+=(b.x()-a.x())*(a.y()+b.y());" it gives spurious results